# How to make Xcode to use custom DTD for autocompletion?

Tags: xml, xcode, autocomplete, dtd

Is there easy way to make Xcode to use custom DTD for autocompletion or would it require one to write extension to the development environment to get things to work? Eclipse has support for using DTD's for autocompletion of XML files but is there similar feature in Xcode?

Structure of XML files used in our application in defined in DTD so it would be extremely helpful to get good autocomplete of all possible tags and attributes to Xcode.

Comment: Me too. (I'm hoping for some way to get doxygen autocomplete for xcode, kind-of like how Eclipse will populate your javadoc for you.)

Comment: Still no answer? :( Would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found this when searching through my filesystem:

/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Resources/*.xclangspec

These files may be of interest to you.

Comment: Tried to find on latest Xcode but it seems there isn't those files. Anyway, those could be on path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFramework if there would be such framework available.